# "I am going to school" = "I am gonna school"?

Tags: grammar

If "gonna" is a short form for "going to"

Can 'I am going to school' be said as 'I am gonna school'?

For clarification here, "school" is a noun.

Comment: My best advice is that never use it in a formal writing. In addition the following link might give you a rough idea about that : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/188/using-gonna-in-written-english

Comment: In spoken English, in my dialect anyway, in a sentence like "I'm going to school", I would elide the *to* with *school* rather than the verb: "I'm goin' t'school." On the other hand, I would say "I'm gonna school you." I would guess that the difference is in whether the *to* is part of an infinitive verb or part of an object phrase (or howsomever the grammar actually works, which I am no expert on) and probably has something to do with how I would naturally assign emphasis to the words in the sentence.

Comment: Short answer: no, you _never_ say that. Use 'gonna' only in the same instances where you would use 'will', that is, referring to the future.

Comment: They're both contracted, but to different forms. ['ɡənə] occurs before an infinitive (it's a periphrastic modal auxiliary), and ['ɡowənə] occurs before a noun (it's a motion verb + a directional preposition). The fact that written English doesn't account for the difference is hardly surprising; written English doesn't account for actual speech very well at all.

Comment: Writing dialect, you might even go for 'Ah'm gonna school', but unless there is a specific reason not to use standard English, stick with 'I'm (or I am) going to school'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Gonna" is shorthand for "going to" (just like "wanna" is shorthand for "want to") but gonna is used in place of the future tense of "going to". [This link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv165.shtml) explains it better.

In your example, "gonna" works if you add a word, specifically a verb.

> I am gonna head to school.

Also, this:

> I am gonna go to school.

Even though, if you wrote it out it would say

> I am going to go to school.

Even though "gonna" is supposed to be "going to", in the sentence "I am going to school," the verb "am" (Present of to be) is an auxillary verb and combining this with "going" makes the present progressive form of to go. Uh, I guess [this link](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/auxiliaryverb.htm) could help a little here.

But from what I can tell, there's always an infinitive form in sentences where "gonna" replaces the present progressive form of "to go". The structure seems to be something like...
[Present progressive form of "to go"] + [infinitive form of secondary verb] == gonna + [verb]

See these examples:

> I am going **to fight** him to the death -> I am **gonna fight** him to the death
>
> I am going **to hang** out at the mall -> I am **gonna hang** out at the mall
>
> It's not normal, but that's what I am going **to do** -> It's not normal, but that's what I am **gonna do**

Answer (score 0):

Some verbs can only be used with an object. Since "I am gonna school" doesn't make sense while "I am gonna school you" does, "gonna" is possibly such a verb.

Comment: see clarification from OP. School is intended as a noun here.

Answer (score 0):

"Gonna" should stick with the most informal prose, and also be followed by a verb, e.g. Tonight, I'm gonna have some fun by the lake".

Answer (score 0):

*Going to sth* is a way of expressing a future action or intention, but not every colocation of the words *going* and *to* means that the phrase is to be interpreted this way. *To sth* is not necessarily an infinitive; it may also be a prepositional phrase headed by *to* and referring to a place.

*Gonna* is quite informal, I wouldn't say that using it in the manner you suggest is proscribed, but I have only rarely encountered it.

*Gonna* as a contraction of *going to* is usually used for the first usage, at least in American English. *I'm gonna Portland for New Years'* makes me think *Portland* is being used as a verb, to do something that is evocative of Portland (perhaps, drive around in a Subaru for a while and then drink a microbrew). *I'm gonna the park* just looks wrong; if I wanted to affect the particular speech pattern in writing, I would write something like

> I'm goin' t' the park.

As others have noted, I would strongly avoid *gonna* in written communication in general. It isn't much shorter than *going to*, so it doesn't save you much time to write, and like most contractions, is too casual for use in a business or academic setting.

Comment: What do you mean by _sth_?

Comment: I think it's supposed to similar to the way we use _nth_ in math. He says "to sth is not necessarily an infinitive," so it might be the same as "denoting an unspecified verb"?

Comment: @IQAndreas I mean *something*, in the loosest sense, to represent the basic word pattern. The same pattern may be an infinitive phrase or a prepositional phrase depending on the context.

Comment: @choster Damn it man! This is a site for lovers of the English language. Remove thine ambiguity and spell out _something_ as the lord himself did intend for it! Leave your slothful abbreviations at the door.

Comment: Seriously though, [perhaps underscores would work instead](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4475/5438)? They would likely be more clear.